# Validation message move button on focusout and it prevents onclick event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, user-interface

I have a JQuery validation that validates a field on focusout and show a label under the field when there's an error.

When I focus the field and enter an invalid value and click on the button under the field for the first time, so the validation message appears, the error message show because of the focusout event and the click event of the button doesn't trigger.

I tried to add a preventdefault on the focusout event when the relatedTarget of the event is my button and it worked because the validation didn't trigger. But I don't think it's a good way to correct this problem, because I have to prevent the validation for all the buttons or controls in my application that I have, so the validation seems useless.

I could trigger the validation on keyup instead so the validation message would be there already when the focusout trigger, but when there's a validation that validate if the field is 10 characters long for exemple, it would show the error message before the user event entered a complete value.

I can put my validation message elsewhere so it doesn't move my button, but the validation message under the field is a norm where I work.

In the example below, I have the following situations where the field has a validation of MaxLength(5) :

- When I first click on the button, I have the alert.
- When I enter 'abc' in the field and click on the button, I have the alert.
- When I enter '123456' in the field and click outside the field, I have the error message Under the field and then if I click on the button I have the alert.
- When I enter '123456' in the field and click on the button, I have the message Under the field but no alert.

My model :

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TestClickValdiation.Models
{
    public class TestValidation
    {
        [MaxLength(5)]
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewStart :

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Layout :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

My view :

```
@model TestClickValdiation.Models.TestValidation

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Go", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Test, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Test)
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="window.alert('hello');">Submit</button>
}
```

global.asax :

```cs
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace TestClickValdiation
{
    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

My controller :

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestClickValdiation.Models;

namespace TestClickValdiation.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            TestValidation test = new TestValidation();
            return View(test);
        }

        public ActionResult Go(TestValidation test)
        {
            return View("Index", test);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is for the last situation to show the validation message and also show the alert. So the following step :

- Enter '123456' in the field
- Click on the button
- The message under the field show.
- The alert shows.

Now only the message Under the field show.

---

I removed the .min from my jQuery import to debug Inside it and test where the focusout and maxlength attribute are used.

The focusout event is in jQuery.validate.js :

```js
        onfocusout: function( element ) {
            if ( !this.checkable( element ) && ( element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional( element ) ) ) {
                this.element( element );
            }
        },
```

After that the element is called and Inside it the check function is called and then the validation method is called for each rules (maxlength in this case)

```js
        check: function( element ) {
            element = this.validationTargetFor( this.clean( element ) );

            var rules = $( element ).rules(),
                rulesCount = $.map( rules, function( n, i ) {
                    return i;
                } ).length,
                dependencyMismatch = false,
                val = this.elementValue( element ),
                result, method, rule, normalizer;

            // Prioritize the local normalizer defined for this element over the global one
            // if the former exists, otherwise user the global one in case it exists.
            if ( typeof rules.normalizer === "function" ) {
                normalizer = rules.normalizer;
            } else if ( typeof this.settings.normalizer === "function" ) {
                normalizer = this.settings.normalizer;
            }

            // If normalizer is defined, then call it to retreive the changed value instead
            // of using the real one.
            // Note that `this` in the normalizer is `element`.
            if ( normalizer ) {
                val = normalizer.call( element, val );

                if ( typeof val !== "string" ) {
                    throw new TypeError( "The normalizer should return a string value." );
                }

                // Delete the normalizer from rules to avoid treating it as a pre-defined method.
                delete rules.normalizer;
            }

            for ( method in rules ) {
                rule = { method: method, parameters: rules[ method ] };
                try {
                    result = $.validator.methods[ method ].call( this, val, element, rule.parameters );
...
```

And then the maxlength validation method

```js
        // https://jqueryvalidation.org/maxlength-method/
        maxlength: function( value, element, param ) {
            var length = $.isArray( value ) ? value.length : this.getLength( value, element );
            return this.optional( element ) || length <= param;
        },
```

Comment: You are not doing JQuery Validation. You are doing ASP.NET validation which happens on the server. Where is the lostfocus code? This doesn't seem like all the relevant code.

Comment: I removed the min on my references to jQuery and entered in debug inside and the focusout (sorry it's not lostfocus). The code of the focusout is Inside jQuery.validate.js : 
```
  onfocusout: function( element ) {
   if ( !this.checkable( element ) && ( element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional( element ) ) ) {
    this.element( element );
   }
  },
```
after that check is called and the maxlength validation is called

Comment: I edited my question to add this part and other files in my code. Il really seems like a jQuery validation.